# the first link is redirecting to the login page but the three additional DWG links are not

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

Need to redirect the links with DWG files in the link to redirect to the log in page right now only the first link redirects.

```
{% if customer %}
  <script>
    const dwgLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.dwg-disabled');
    const redirectBtn = document.querySelector('.pdf-redirect');
    redirectBtn.classList.remove('pdf-redirect')
    dwgLinks.forEach(link => {
      link.classList.remove('dwg-disabled')
    })
  </script>
{% endif %}

<script>
  const redirectBtn = document.querySelector('.pdf-redirect')
  redirectBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location.href = '/account/login'
  })
</script>
```